# how to get a script value in html in 'response.text' using re.search?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-re

I have an HTML file, and this file contains several scripts specifically in the last script contains a value that I would like to get

I need to get the hash value found here

```
extend(cur, { "hash": "13334a0e457f0793ec", "loginHost": "login", "sureBoxText": false, "strongCode": 0, "joinParams": false, "validationType": 3, "resendDelay": 120, "calledPhoneLen": 4, "calledPhoneExcludeCountries": [1, 49, 200] });
```

for this i used

```
import re

with open("test.html", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    html = f.read()

hash = re.search(r'{ "hash": "(.*?)",', html).group(1)
```

works perfectly, but when I try to do the same using directly from the request the error.

```
with requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies) as response:
        if response.status_code == 200:
            html = response.content
            hash = re.search(r'{ "hash": "(.*?)",', html).group(1)
            return hash
```

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

then I performed a simple test where I saved the 'response.text' in an html file and tried to read as the first way, the error remained
soon after I entered the file and in my vscode I clicked to format the file, it fixed the entire html file, I performed the test and it worked.
i need a way where it does the formatting from 'response.text' to html so i can get my value, or if there's another way i don't know i'm willing to learn.

**OBS**
the hash value is found in 'response.text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting `html` to a string using `str()`:

```
hash = re.search(r'{ "hash": "(.*?)",', str(html)).group(1)
```

**Edit**: your regular expression isn't correct, change it to:

```
hash = re.search(r'"hash":"(.*?)",', str(html)).group(1)
```

Comment: error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @DamiDoug There's probably a problem with the regular expression, what happens if you remove the `str()`, does it still work?

Comment: the error keeps

Comment: @DamiDoug So the problem is with the regular expression since it doesn't find a match, it returns `None`, hence you receive an error, consider tweaking the regular expression a bit to correctly find a match. What's the URL?

Comment: @DamiDoug See my edit

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the bytes to string:

```
re.search(r'{ "hash": "(.*?)",', html.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?

Comment: @DamiDoug your error specifies that you have bytes, so you need to decode to get a string. What is the type of `html`?

Comment: I don't know the type, I just order. how can i see the type

Comment: You can add `print(type(html))` in your function

Comment: Type <class 'bytes'>

Comment: Then it should have a `decode` method

Comment: Then it should have a `decode` method

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `response.text` which is "Content of the response, in unicode.". See https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text

```
with requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies) as response:
        if response.status_code == 200:
            html = response.text
            hash = re.search(r'{ "hash": "(.*?)",', html).group(1)
            return hash
```